# Error handling not working. Javascript Try Catch

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

```
try {
  console.log(Hello World);
}
catch (error) {
  console.log(error.name);
  console.log(error.message);
}
```

Output:

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

No idea why SyntaxError is not being catch.

Is there any mistake in my code or due to some JavaScript concepts I am getting this error

Comment: Syntax errors are detected before the code runs, so they cannot be caught by an exception handler.

Comment: Oh also the syntax error is that `Hello World` should be `"Hello World"`, with quotes.

Comment: Yes I want SyntaxError to revise try and catch. so I didn't added " " quotes

Comment: Well you want something that cannot happen. The parser has to interpret the meaning of the code **before** the code runs.

Comment: Got it.  Got to learn something new. Thank You.

Comment: Learning something new is what makes this site useful :) I am happy for you, and good luck!